# What API should I use for a video call between two users?

Tags: video

I own a job seeking platform and at this point I want to integrate an online interview between the job seeker and the recruiter. I want to ask you guys whether I should use an API or I should create my own video streaming app, or I am overthinking this and there is a really easy way to do it.

Basically I want two users to be able to video (and audio) call each other and have a conversation. What are my options?

Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use skype, which will be the easier way.
The other option is about WebRTC, this will be much more effort for you.